# Truffle Test AssertionError: error message must contain revert

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, erc-20, truffle-test

I can't figure out why this error occurs

Here my test js code:

```
var YarockToken = artifacts.require("./YarockToken.sol");

contract('YarockToken', function(accounts) {
  var tokenInstance;

  it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
    return YarockToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return tokenInstance.name();
    }).then(function(name) {
      assert.equal(name, 'Yarock Token', 'has the correct name');
      return tokenInstance.symbol();
    }).then(function(symbol) {
      assert.equal(symbol, 'YAROCK', 'has the correct symbol');
      return tokenInstance.standard();
    }).then(function(standard) {
      assert.equal(standard, 'Yarock Token v1.0', 'has the correct standard');
    });
  })

  it('allocates the initial supply upon deployment', function() {
    return YarockToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
    }).then(function(totalSupply) {
      assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 1000000, 'sets the total supply to 1,000,000');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(adminBalance) {
      assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(), 1000000, 'it allocates the initial supply to the admin account');
    });
  });

  it('transfers token ownership', function() {
    return YarockToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      // Test `require` statement first by transferring something larger than the sender's balance
      return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'error message must contain revert');
 
 })
    })
});
```

and here my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
contract YarockToken {
    string  public name = "Yarock Token";
    string  public symbol = "YAROCK";
    string  public standard = "Yarock Token v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;

    }

}
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
      Contract: YarockToken
    ✓ initializes the contract with the correct values (238ms)
    ✓ allocates the initial supply upon deployment (123ms)
    1) transfers token ownership
    > No events were emitted


  2 passing (541ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: YarockToken
       transfers token ownership:
     AssertionError: error message must contain revert
      at /Users/Kantemirovs/token_sale/test/YarockToken.js:39:7
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Can someone please enlighten me about this ??

Comment: Try in the last test `tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 99999999999999999999999)` instead, ie remove `.call`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found the solution on Github. Basically, you need to delete indexOf() function after error.message so it should look like this

```
assert(error.message, 'error message must contain revert');
```

Here is your answer:  https://github.com/dappuniversity/token_sale/issues/27

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46757)

Comment: Do you have a better answer than the link?

Answer (score 0):

I just completed my transfer function and test passed.

```
  //Throw if caller doesn't have funds
//Trigger transfer Event
//return boolean
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    return true;
}
```

Test Impl:

```
 it("transfers tokens ownership", function() {
    return HanuToken.deployed().then(function(tok) {
      var token = tok;
      return token.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
        assert(error.message.toString().indexOf('revert') >=0, 'error msg must contains revert');
    });
});
```